# Android: no running Device

Tags: android, launching-application, mobile-devices

I want to run my Android Project iwrote with emulators on my Android Device. The Device is Connected on an USB-Port. When I start the "Android Device Chooser" nothing happens. No running device in the "Choose a running Android Device"-Table is displayed. 
I tried to reboot the system(PC and Smartphone) while connecting. I tried every USB mode. I tried another Device( G1 and HTC Desire). Unknown Source is always true.
I tried another Eclipse-Version(64 and 32 bit), tried another SDK(64 and 32 bit) and reinstalled the android sdk. 
I still can't see any device. Everything worked fine on my old 32 bit system. Now i have to work with my 64 bit lenovo. (both windows 7)
somebody got another idea?
Thank you.
Fabian

Comment: Are correct drivers installed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See this link for detailed info: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html#setting-up

In short, you have to:

1. Mark your app as debuggable (in Manifest)
2. Allow USB debug on your device (Settings->Application)
3. And, if developing in Windows, download drivers.

Comment: ... the download drivers. I would have sworn i installed them the first time, but forgot yesterday when i reinstalled the sdk. Thanks Corkscreewe and bob, both answers are useful! ... and sorry that i asked the question again, i thought the answer wasn't in one of the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try command line "adb devices" to see if your phone is detected ok. Except limited number of phones supported by Android by default, manufacturer-supplied setup needs to be used to start usb mode. In my case, Vodafone 845, setup was contained in phone storage. So after phone was detected as normal usb storage, I located that utility and simply ran it. Then it started to be detected as android phone.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to this dilema i found here. If you are on windows,

Make sure you have install the google usb driver

Ensure USB Debugging is enabled.

download the adbdriver setup from http://adbdriver.com/downloads/

just follow the wizard and install, automatically it should see your device or you try restarting android studio.

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable USB Debugging :

   Setting - About Phone - Tap Build Number 5 times.

   Then go to : Setting - Developer Options - Turn On Usb Debugging.
2. Download and install Wondershare Mobile Go / Snappea. That program will download and install your android device.
3. If this popup appears, click allow.

[image: allow]